# RichTextBox is not updating in Cross thread operation

Tags: c#, multithreading

here is my sample code:

```
//------this is just GUI Form which is having RichTextBox (Access declared as Public)
//

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public void function1()
   {
      ThreadStart t= function2;
      Thread tStart= new Thread(t);
      tStart.Start();
   }

   public void function2()
   {
   //Calling function3 which is in another class
   }
}


//------this is just Class, not GUI Form
class secondClass: Form1
{

   public void function3()
   {
      Form1 f =new Form1();
      //Updating the RichTextBox(which is created in Form1 GUI with Public access)
      f.richTextBox1.AppendText("sample text");
   }

}
```

I tried by invoking the `richTextBox1` control and my code running without error, but `richtextbox` is not getting updated.

What i have to do to update my status frequently in `richTextBox` from another class function?

Answer (score 2):

Your porblem is here:

```
public void function3()
{
Form1 f =new Form1();
//Updating the RichTextBox(which is created in Form1 GUI with Public access)
f.richTextBox1.AppendText("sample text");
}
```

You create another instance of the Form and make changes to that `richTextBox` - not initial one.

To make this work you should set values of UI controls in their code-behind class using `Invoke` method as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx). Functions from other classes should use parameters for any in and out values.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your RichTextBox from Form1 to function3

```
    //function inside form1
    public void function2() {
        function3(this.richTextBox1);
    }
```

Then update richTextBox from another thread/class using invoke

```
    //function in another thread
    public void function3(RichTextBox r)
    {
        r.InvokeIfRequired((value) => r.AppendText(value), "asd");
    }
```